# Ошибка при запуске: cannot find symbol variable

Tags: java, android

Объявил метод, вызываемый при нажатии кнопки

```
public void sendActionNotification(View v) {
        NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        int ic2 = R.drawable.myicon;

        Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setTicker("Test message")
                .setContentTitle("title message")
                .setContentText("text test message")
                .setSmallIcon(ic2).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.myicon, "Open", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.myicon, "Close", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.myicon, "Other", pIntent)
                .build();
        builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notifyManager.notify(0, builder);
    }
```

В папку res/drawable  добавил png картинку с именем myicon.
Во время запуска проекта отображается ошибка 4 раза

```
error: cannot find symbol variable myicon
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Пробовал создать xml в drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_delete">
    </item>

</selector>
```

и данный вариант работал корректно. Но меня интересует сторонняя картинка, отсутствующая в стандартной библиотеке

Comment: Косяк среды. `clean` сделайте и ребилд проекта. Должно помочь.

Comment: @Suvitruf в том то и проблема - пробовал. Так же на англоязычном stackowerflow видел вариант с использованием старой api - но и тут нет, использую 19

Comment: Что-то подобное у меня было, я не помню как ее разрешил. Но там что-то было связанно с тем что я не все варианты картинки залил(mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi). За ответ это не сойдет, но вроде бы с чем-то таким связанно.

Comment: Гляньте, может android.R импортнули. А так обычно clean/rebuild project помогает как правило..

Comment: @АндроидАндроид как раз во время clean/rebuild project ошибка и возникает с пометкой Gradle Message Build